# Hoare Monitor implementation using semaphores?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, semaphore, concurrent-programming, binary-semaphore

it is my exam in 4 days and I just spoke to my lectuer and he has been extremely unclear about this part of the lecture and I really struggled along with many students how to understand this.

Basiclly, if you wanna implement Hoare monitor using semaphore, what is the sequences of steps involved?

Below is the pseudocode
[image]

[image: one[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x33Bw.png)

**Update:**

I am starting to get it now

so the 1st slide is for the process accessing the monitor

if you are the only one, then you call wait(mutex)

get into the monitor do your stuff and leave

if there is something waiting to get into the monitor then you up the next semaphore, that is the quene of waiting process to get into the semaphore. else if you are the only one in the monitor then you exit and up mutex so someone else can get into the mutex

for the 2nd slide with the wait(condition) and signal(condition)

when u wait(c):
c_count++ //number of process waiting for this condition, increment by one
if(next_count>0) up(next) //if number of waiting process that want t get into the monitor is more than zero, up(next), unblock one of the waiting process

else up(mutex)  //if you are the only one then up mutex so someone else get in
down(c_sem) // block yourself to sleep
c_count-- //you wake up so number of process waiting for this condition decrement

for the signal(c) part:

if(c_count>0) // if number of process waiting for this condition is bigger than 0

next_counter++ //number of process wanting to get into the monitor increment by one
up(c_sem); // unblock one of the process waiting for this condition
down(next) //if a spot is available, down this otherwise get block and join list of waiting processes
next_count--; //you wake up and try to get into the monitor

Comment: One of the things we don't know is what are the operations defined on your semaphores?  Your semaphores either need to put the process in a wait state if not acquired (clearly not the case in your example) or you need to know the value of the semaphore (never done in your example). 

The next_count and c_count variables are redundant. One should not be incrementing variables non-atomically  (ie with ++) in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: the semaphore basiclly if it is down and it is zero then it will put the processes into a list of waiting process (block), otherwise decrement the resources. for the up operation, if there is process waiting then take this out and start it run, otherwise increment the resources

Comment: One semaphore is the count of tasks having access to the monitor (1 or 0). The other semaphore is the count of tasks waiting to gain access to the monitor (0 … n).

Comment: which semaphore implement the lock that you are talking about? is it just the One semaphore is the count of tasks having access to the monitor (1 or 0)??

Comment: If you were to implement the lock using the basic semaphores, you'd need both semaphores, as is shown in the example with errors.

Comment: The bit I am most confused is that yes, every process comes in and down the mutex and if it is only process trying to access the monitor and no other process trying, then it up the mutex, otherwise it up next. Then how does other process gets in if the mutex was never up?

Answer (score 3):

Man, I can see why you are confused. The problem here is that this example merges two concepts.

A semaphore is a form of mutex. In the abstract, a mutex is just a variable that can be atomically incremented or decremented. Your up function increments. Your down function decrements event if multiple process are up'ing or down'ing at the same time. If you just make up equivalent to  count = count + 1 you would get random results if multiple processes tried to increment at the same time.

In the real world (outside academia) a semaphore does more than just increment. You can wait on a semaphore as well.

So, if I do

```
 real_world_down (semaphore)
```

My process decrements the semaphore. If no process (or thread) has locked the semaphore (usually = 0, with 1 being the starting point), my process continues. If another process has already locked the semaphore (value after down < 0), my process waits.

When the process that has locked the semaphore finishes and does

```
 real_world_up (semaphore)
```

The operating system picks one of the waiting processes to run automatically.

Thus your Hoare monitor looks like

```
  var 
     semaphore ; 
  Procedure Monitor

       real_world_down (semaphore) ;

       /* do whatever you want */

       real_world_up (semaphore) ;

 End ;
```

Or we could write it as:

```
  var 
     semaphore ; 
  Procedure Monitor

       lock (semaphore) ;

       /* do whatever you want */

       unlock (semaphore) ;

 End ;
```

That's the monitor part.  The part about your example that is confusing is that it is a poorly written lock/unlock using academic semaphores that just increment and decrement atomically and have no knowledge of who is waiting on them.

It's wait is equivalent to my lock.
It's equivalent to my unlock is totally FUed.

At this point I would leave as an exercise for you to create a lock function that will only allow one process/thread to acquire the lock using a pair of semaphores but will allow multiple processes to wait and, when unlocked, will allow one waiting process/thread to continue.

It needs an unlock function that will unlock the mutex pair to allow one process/thread to continue.

Comment: what about signal and wait? any comments on that?

Comment: real_world_up (semaphore) ; is the part where he check if next count> 0?

Comment: WAIT is entirely equivalent to what I show as LOCK.  If you wanted to implement these as semaphores, you could have manage next_count in both the LOCK and WAIT methods (or whatever you call them). Your examples are implementing a spin lock (but they have left off the loop). As I said, I can see why you're confused.

Comment: I am not very sure what you mean here, any possibility u can illustrate with an example, apology on this, but just getting a bit stressed about the exam.

Comment: can u also comment if my interpretation is correct in my update above?

Comment: I am having my exams in about 4 hours, any chance of a full solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - 2 hours is not really much time to calm you down, I guess - so I don't even try.

On the other hand: it's an exam, not a hackathon. Having said this, ... why don't you stick to the academic level that the slides of your professor have.

If you want a different version of explaining the fundamental work of the genius C.A.R. Hoare than have a look at this PowerPoint - you can read it all but the most important page for you should be page 15: [MonitorPPT](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/teaching/cs3/os/slides/monitor.ppt)

And: in case you want to read the original paper after the exam - to prepare for fighting for points that you didn't get or just for fun - here it is: [C.A.R. Hoare - Monitors: An Operating System 
Structuring Concept](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~shanlu/teaching/33100_fa15/papers/hoare-monitors.pdf)

All the best for your exam, Tom!